# How can I check index in array 2 dimensional without loop in php?

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I try like this :

```
<?php 
    $list_team = array( 
                (object)array(
                    'id' => 1, 
                    'name' => 'chelsea.jpg'
                ),
                (object)array(
                    'id' => 2, 
                    'name' => 'mu.jpg'
                ),
                (object)array(
                    'id' => 3, 
                    'name' => 'arsenal.jpg'
                ),
            );

    $team = 'chelsea.jpg';

    echo '<pre>';print_r($team);echo '</pre>';
    echo '<pre>';print_r($list_team);echo '</pre>';

    foreach($list_team as $key => $value) {
        if($value->name == $team)
            $team_selected = $team;
    }
    echo '<pre>';print_r($team_selected);echo '</pre>';
    die();
?>
```

If the code executed, the result like this :

```
chelsea.jpg

Array

(

[0] => stdClass Object   ( [id] => 1

[name] => chelsea.jpg

)

[1] => stdClass Object

(

[id] => 2

[name] => mu.jpg

)

[2] => stdClass Object

(

[id] => 3

[name] => arsenal.jpg

)

)

chelsea.jpg
```

The code using loop

But, I do not want to use a loop

How can I do it?

Comment: what do you want exactly? I don't understand what index you want. Are you looking for the id value withing the same object where the parameter name matches your var `$team`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php), and [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

```
<?php

$list_team = array( 
                (object)array(
                    'id' => 1, 
                    'name' => 'chelsea.jpg'
                ),
                (object)array(
                    'id' => 2, 
                    'name' => 'mu.jpg'
                ),
                (object)array(
                    'id' => 3, 
                    'name' => 'arsenal.jpg'
                ),
            );

    $team = 'chelsea.jpg';

    // array column, returns all value of sub array, with key name
    // array_search will return key
    $key = array_search($team, array_column($list_team, 'name'));

    if($key!==false){

        // your object will be
        print_r($list_team[$key]);

        // access remaining..
        echo $list_team[$key]->name.' '. $list_team[$key]->id.PHP_EOL;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
$key = array_search($team, array_column($list_team, 'name'));
$team_selected = $list_team[$key]->name;
```

This will search array with `name` and return the and return the `key` of the main array and you can use that to access the contents of the nested array and assign the value to. `$team_selected`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access specific attributes in multidimensional arrays, you can do the following thing.

For example, return the ID of the first array:

```
echo $list_team[0]["id"];
```

Simply change the `[0]` to `[1]` or whatever to mention the array you wanna call, and then simply use the attribute. But if you wanna print the whole array, I really recommend you to stay on loops. With loops you're sure you get all elements. Lets say you hardcode it like I said and then a month later you add 10 new arrays, so you'll have to edit your whole code.