# Loop into an array if I have a key in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

How can I loop into the `plans` datas of this array:

```
$currencies = array(
    array(
        'currency' => 'mxn', 
        'sign'     => '$',
        'plans'    => array(
            'tiny'   => 429,
            'small'  => 1319,
            'medium' => 3399,
            'big'    => 6669
        )
    ),
    array(
        'currency' => 'usd', 
        'sign'     => '$',
        'plans'    => array(
            'tiny'   => 29,
            'small'  => 319,
            'medium' => 399,
            'big'    => 669
        )
    )
);
```

If I have only the `currency` ?

```
$currency = 'mxn';
```

I tried:

```
foreach($currencies as $currency => $info) {
    if($info['currency'] = 'mxn') {
        ....
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your if statement is using an assignment operator (single =) and should be equal (double ==) or identical (triple ===).

Comment: This looks close: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46690169/how-can-i-check-index-in-array-2-dimensional-without-loop-in-php  I'll see if I can find a better one (there are hundreds of related pages to sift through).

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13933454/get-the-sub-array-having-a-particular-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly you want to loop the array "plans" when the "currency" is  equal to 'mxn'. Here is:

```
<?php
foreach($currencies as $key => $data) {
  if($data['currency'] == 'mxn')
  {
    echo 'List of plans: <br />';
    foreach($data['plans'] as $item){
        echo $item.'<br />';
    }
  }
}
?>
```

First, the code checks which array is the mxn currency and do a loop on the "plans" array.

Just to complement the post with a **simplified alternative**:

```
<?php
$key = array_search('mxn', array_column($currencies, 'currency'));
foreach($currencies[$key]['plans'] as $item){
    echo $item.'<br />';
}
?>
```

Comment: This is not a refined answer because it will continue to iterate after the targeted subarray is found.  There is a combination of php functions that offers a superior method.

Comment: I know that. I always try to explain with more code to people understand what's exactly happening but I posted a simplified or "superior" method. Thanks for your concern @mickmackusa

Answer (score 0):

This question is an excellent opportunity to demonstrate a better way.

Code: (Demo:   https://3v4l.org/dU09B  )

```
$currencies = [
    'mxn' => [
        'sign'  => '$',
        'plans' => [
            'tiny'   =>  429,
            'small'  => 1319,
            'medium' => 3399,
            'big'    => 6669
        ]
    ],
    'usd' => [
        'sign'  => '$',
        'plans' => [
            'tiny'   =>  29,
            'small'  => 319,
            'medium' => 399,
            'big'    => 669
        ]
    ]
];

$currency='mxn';

if(!isset($currencies[$currency])){
    echo "$currency was not found in the currencies array.";
}else{
    echo "In $currency:\n";
    foreach($currencies[$currency]['plans'] as $size=>$price){
        echo "\t$size costs {$currencies[$currency]['sign']}$price\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
In mxn:
    tiny costs $429
    small costs $1319
    medium costs $3399
    big costs $6669
```

Explanation:

Because the currency names will logically be unique, you can reduce the overall size of your lookup array by declaring the currency names as subarray keys.

If you were to store this same data in a database, you would assign the currency name as the Primary Key.

As a matter of improved efficiency and direct coding, the new array structure will allow you to swiftly determine if your desired currency exists in the multi-dimensional array using `isset()`.

Your question title asks: *Loop into an array if I have a key in PHP*  I take this to mean that it is possible that the *needle* may not be in the *haystack*.  Maybe this is not what you mean, but this consideration is important to build into your code.

Verifying that the key exists in the multidimensional array is essential (to avoid a Notice ftom php) before attempting to use the key.

---

If you are not able or interested in modifying your data structure, then be sure that you employ two pieces of best practice:

1. `break` your searching `foreach` loop after your currency is found; or call `array_search()` which does this for you.  Iterating the remaining items in your array after you've received the desired data is wasteful/inefficient.
2. Write a condition that handles the possibility of the currency not being found. Because trying to access: `$currencies[false]` isn't going to work out well for you.